# Cursor blinking with text "A N D R O I D _" after boot logo while android boot up

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-animation, boot

I am trying to change linux boot up logo and able to get my own image. But after that logo is displayed for some time I am getting "A N D R O I D _ " text before boot animation starts. The cursor is staying there itself even after android is completely booted.

It is affecting the UI.

How can this text be removed from my custom build?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is defined in the [/system/core/init/init.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4.3_r1/init/init.c#660) file (or [init.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/init.cpp) in Android v5 and above).

It's possible to define a custom boot animation to replace this.

There's a detailed explanation of the custom boot animation code here: http://www.programering.com/a/MDMykTNwATc.html